# Nuxt - Page not loading correctly after "yarn generate"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a simple nuxt app with a page that is under the directory structure:

```
pages
   callback
       index.vue
```

The app is generated using "universal" mode. My issue is that when I run the app locally (i.e. yarn dev) the callback page displays perfectly and works correctly. However when I run yarn generate and then serve the dist folder, the pages contains a couple of minor visual errors. No console errors or network errors, but it displays slightly broken. The issues are: a specific icon doesn't load (hamburger menu) and a dropdown / select component fails to initialise properly and display its placeholder until clicked.

These are components that are already built and work elsewhere in the app but specifically on this page, when generated, they do not.

I enabled devtools on the build output and the only difference I could see between the version running locally and the version that is generated is that when I navigate to the callback route, the generated output does not seem to receive the "Active" flag in the vue devtools.

I thought this was strange and read up about navigable links and hidden pages (as this page is not currently linked to from anywhere on the site) and tried numerous methods but nothing has worked. The closest I could get was by creating a NuxtLink element on the home page linking to the callback route. When I did this, after clicking the link the page works as expected and the active flag is set in the routes tab in the devtools. But not if I navigate to it via the url bar.

I've read over the documentation on nuxt and vue router extensively but can't seem to find anything that will solve the issue.

Comment: Maybe this is due to some relative paths being broken? Eg. '../src/img/bruger.png' which is not available when yo serve the dist folder.

Maybe this helps: 
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I don't think that's possible because as I said in my post, when I navigate to the page via a link, everything works just fine. It's only when I type the url straight into the address bar that the error occurs. Which sucks because it's intended as a landing page from an email basically.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn generate` is for deploying static sites, whereas your target is set to universal. Run `yarn build` and `yarn start` to deploy in universal mode.

See the docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands).

Comment: That's good to know, I take your point, but unfortunately when I do this the issue still remains. Currently the only way I can get the app to display correctly is using yarn dev. It's very strange. I actually tried building in static mode too as my deployment environment is a static serve azure app but it didn't work either.

Comment: Very strange indeed! So you run dev, everything is fine, you run build/start and everything is off? Are you sure you’re not viewing a cached version of the static app, you’re definitely viewing the build/start version on the correct port number etc? You’ve forced a hard refresh?

Comment: It's weird it's not even like the whole app is off. Just two little display problems on one page... Which is even built using components that work elsewhere in the app! Hard refresh etc. doesn't seem to do anything either unfortunately.